# from p-1 algorithm in FP to design a p+1 algorithm in FP^2

Tags: number-theory, big-numbers

the (p-1) algorithm is based on the properties of the field of the finite field
, using instead the field  2̅̅, develop a (p+1)-factoring algorithm for
use when a private P factor of N is such that (p+1) is B-powersmooth for
some reasonable bound B.